# What restrictions exist on the number of the requests to the Facebook API?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an application for Facebook.

What restrictions exist on the number of the request to the Facebook API? Are there restrictions by count of calls per time?

Also are there similar restrictions in working with the Facebook Ads API?

I find that if I make over 800 call in a row:

```
$request = $facebook->api('/'.$row['fb_uid'].'/feed', 'POST', array('message'=>'Facebook API Test №'.$i.' time '.gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()) ));
```

after the 79th call, I get error:

```
Err type: OAuthException
Err msg: (#1) An unknown error occurred
```

And this Program Application will be banned for this facebook user on two days.

Where get all information about restrictions? I can't find this info on http://developers.facebook.com

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=100502990045478

Answer (score 1):

The rate limit is 600 calls in 600 seconds as stated here: http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-Facebook-Open-Graph-API-rate-limit